# git filter-branch fails on a comparison bash syntax

Tags: git, bash

I wrote a script to rewrite a repo as if the files have been in a subfolder.

This one worked:

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'd="subfolder"; [ ! -f "$d" ] && mkdir -p "$d" && for file in *; do if [ "$file" != "$d" ]; then mv "$file" "$d"; fi; done' -- test
```

While this one returned an error which says `Rewrite a92e7d6bd57d523fdffa227bffdc76d7b9eb7c7a (1/5)tree filter failed`

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'd="subfolder"; [ ! -f "$d" ] && mkdir -p "$d" && for file in *; do [ "$file" != "$d" ] && mv "$file" "$d"; done' -- test
```

I did a further test on the revision a92e7d6bd57d523fdffa227bffdc76d7b9eb7c7a and it also worked as expected:

```
d="subfolder"; [ ! -f "$d" ] && mkdir -p "$d" && for file in *; do [ "$file" != "$d" ] && mv "$file" "$d"; done
```

I am confused: the (if [ ]; then ...; fi) ought to be equivalent to the ([ ] && ...) isn't it? Could someone explain why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer can be found in the following:

```
bash$ for i in a; do false && mv foo bar; done; echo $?
1
bash$ for i in a; do if false; then mv foo bar; fi; done; echo $?
0
```

The two are indeed equivalent in terms of what gets run.  The difference is in the exit status of the shell, if it exits immediately after the `done`.  Git's `filter-branch` script checks the exit status of each filter, and aborts if that is non-zero.

(You can always add: `; true` to the end of a `prog1 && prog2` sequence to force it to succeed.)

Comment: Thank you for reminding me that (false && blah) evaluates an exit status 1 while (if ... fi) evaluate an exit status 0 if there's no error inbetween. However, I can't figure out why we didn't get an exit status 0 since there had been no error between (for ... done)?

Comment: I believe that the very last file in your `for` loop was the sub-folder, so that the test `[ "$file" != "$d" ]` was false.